# Question about principle of equivalence

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle

Set up: Suppose we have a worldline and I have a system of coordinates that can label all points that belong to the worldline (in some macroscopic region of spacetime). The principle of equivalence says that at each point P there exists a change in coordinates that will make the metric tensor at P Lorentzian (this is how I learned it).

Let us call this “inertial” system of coordinates at P: $\xi_{\mu}=\Lambda_{\mu} ^ \nu X_{\nu}$ and those at another point Q as $\xi^{'} _{\mu}=\Lambda^{' \nu} _{\mu} X _{\nu}$ where the $\Lambda$’s are the change of coordinate matrix and $X_{\mu}$ are the original coordinates.

Question: The principle of equivalence guarantees the existence of $\xi_{\mu}$ and $\xi^{'} _{\mu}$ separately, but does it also guarantee that we can find the inertial coordinates to be
$\xi_{\mu}=\xi^{'} _{\mu}$?

If $\xi_{\mu}\neq \xi^{'} _{\mu}$, then wouldn't we see test particles accelerate even at a local level inside a free falling lab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The principle of equivalence says that at each point P there exists a change in coordinates that will make the metric tensor at P Lorentzian

It is actually a little stronger than that. The metric at P is Lorentzian and the metric in the neighborhood of P is Lorentzian to first order.

> The principle of equivalence guarantees the existence of ξμ and ξ′μ separately, but does it also guarantee that we can find the inertial coordinates to be ξμ=ξ′μ?

What you are interested in is Fermi coordinates.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates

With Fermi coordinates if you start with the inertial coordinate basis vectors $\mathbf{e_t}$, $\mathbf{e_x}$, $\mathbf{e_y}$, and $\mathbf{e_z}$ where the $\mathbf{e_i}$ are orthonormal and $\mathbf{e_t}$ is tangent to the worldline at $P$, then you can parallel transport the $\mathbf{e_i}$ along the worldline to $Q$ and they will still be orthonormal.

Additionally, if the worldline is a geodesic then $\mathbf{e_t}$ will be tangent at $Q$ also because geodesics parallel transport their tangent vector. Such parallel transported basis vectors can define a locally (to first order) inertial frame at $Q$.